# Having trouble getting my function to meet while loop condition in Python

Tags: python

my goal is to:
Implement the roll_dice function in hog.py. It takes two arguments: a positive integer called num_rolls (which is the number of dice rolls that will be made) and a dice function (A function that simulates a single dice roll outcome). It returns the number of points scored by rolling the dice that number of times in a turn: either the sum of the outcomes or 1.

It returns 1 when any of the dice outcomes is a 1.

When I debug in PyCharm, it says that current_roll = 2, current_value = 4, num_rolls = 5 and total_sum = 4. This leads me to believe that it only went through the loop once since the current_roll should be 5 since the num_rolls is 5. Also, because the total_sum is only the the current_value. I've tried moving around of the variable assignments but nothing has worked.

Could anyone give me any guidance as to why my function is not looping until current_roll is not < num_rolls? Sorry if this is not clear I am a beginner learner. I can offer any clarification

```
def roll_dice(num_rolls, dice=six_sided):
    current_roll = 1
    total_sum = 0
    current_value = dice()
    while current_roll < num_rolls:
        current_roll += 1
        if current_value == 1 or total_sum == 1:
            return total_sum == 1
        else:
            total_sum = total_sum + current_value
            return total_sum
```

this is what my code is updated to now:

```
    total_sum = 0
    current_roll = 0
    while current_roll < num_rolls:
        current_roll += 1
        current_value = dice()
        if current_value == 1 or total_sum == 1:
            total_sum = 1
            return total_sum
        else:
            total_sum += current_value
            return total_sum
```

I updated my code, but it is still not passing. I added the dice() function into the while loop and changed the total sum = 1. Do you have any idea why it is still not passing?

Comment: can u elaborate `dice()`

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes does this help? : To obtain a single outcome of a dice roll, call dice(). You should call dice() exactly num_rolls times in the body of roll_dice. Remember to call dice() exactly num_rolls times even if Pig Out happens in the middle of rolling. In this way, you correctly simulate rolling all the dice together. Pig Out is when one of the outcomes is 1 and it just returns the sum as 1

Comment: does the answers below help

Comment: @CoolCloud i tried moving my last return statement outside at the same indentation as the while condition and it seems to have looped it now. However, all the times i run the loop it never randomly returns 1 as the sum, which means that it never rolls on 1 which i find it hard to believe. I am also running it in the schools autograder ok and it is still not passing

Comment: oh, im not sure why :(

Answer (score 1):

You are returning inside the while loop,
this will terminate the loop.

move your return statement outside the while loop

Edit:

Move the dice function call within the while loop.
In the current state of your code it will only roll the dice once, and then check that roll `num_rolls` times.

also you are returning `total_sum == 1` this will return `True` or `False` not sure if this is intended

Comment: THE OP SAYS: "i tried moving my last return statement outside at the same indentation as the while condition and it seems to have looped it now. However, all the times i run the loop it never randomly returns 1 as the sum, which means that it never rolls on 1 which i find it hard to believe. I am also running it in the schools autograder ok and it is still not passing"

Comment: @Bendik Knapstad, I updated my code in my original post at the top, but it is still not passing. I added the dice() function into the while loop and changed the total sum = 1. Do you have any idea why it is still not passing?

Answer (score 1):

You are not even using your `dice` function within the loop. Try to rewrite your code in this way:

```
def roll_dice(num_rolls, dice=six_sided):
    total_sum = 0
    rolled_one = False
    # roll a dice num_rolls times
    for current_roll in range(num_rolls):
        # roll a dice
        current_value = dice()
        # if value=1 then remember what happened
        if current_value == 1:
            rolled_one = True
        # add the value to the sum
        total_sum += current_value
    # if you previously rolled a 1 then return 1
    if rolled_one:
        return 1
    # otherwise return the final sum
    else:
        return total_sum
```